# Excel VBA code for auto fill serial number from a select row

Tags: excel, vba

I try with the following code to auto fill the serial number from a data entry form.My problem is that it counts the last rows and  serial number starts from this number. Eg when i enter data into 5th row it counting start from 4. But since it is first row in my counting so it should be 1. How to solve this.

```
Set shSegment = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSegmentName)

iCurrentRow = shSegment.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With shSegment

    
.Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = iCurrentRow - 1
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Explanation is in the comments.

```
Set shSegment = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(sSegmentName)

iCurrentRow = shSegment.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With shSegment
    'Test if previous row is a number
    If IsNumeric(.Cells(iCurrentRow - 1, 1)) Then
        ' If yes, add 1 to its previous row's value
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = .Cells(iCurrentRow - 1, 1) + 1
    Else
        ' If no, reset to 1 (previous row was the header)
        .Cells(iCurrentRow, 1) = 1
    End If
```